# Two jscripts combined in one?

Tags: javascript

2 different jscripts in one:
I have 2 html files with 2 different jscripts.  I want to make an page from 2 html pages.  I want to add the effects from 2.html in the 1.html buttons.  How can I do that?

Here are the 2 html pages

I uploaded those html files in my host
also the other .js files are in

http://antrepolotianproject.net63.net/jscript

The two files are called 1.html and 2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this is really simple, just include the javascript on your pages with `<script>` tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js">
```

Duplicate and change the `src` attribute for script file you need. For your own written JS, make another file such as global.js and include this in the same way.

Comment: i 4got to tell you im such an newbie

Comment: Duplicate that line of code, but change 'jquery-1.3.1.min.js' to the names of you other javascript files. You'll need to cut the custom javascript from 2.html (inside `<script>` tags) and put it in it's own file and include it in 1.html using the above method.

Comment: so i have to move everything within the script tags addit into exaple.js and then add <script type="text/javascript" src="js/example.js"> in 1.html ?

Comment: Yeah everything inside the `<script>` tags, but not the actual tags. I can't help with the exact content as your host has disabled your website.